# the opposite of "Plain English"

Tags: meaning

Imagine that, Alice is writing a report for a news website

> ... With Femtosecond Laser, many kinds of **ophthalmic diseases** could be cured ...

Michael suggests

> "Ophthalmic" sounds too **professional** for ordinary audience to understand, how about "eye diseases"

where Michael uses "**professional**" as the opposite of "**Plain English**", is the use clear and common?

Comment: I would use 'technical' as the opposite of 'plain' in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **"Opthalmic"** sounds too professional for ordinary audience.

It clearly means it's **a medical term** that means *'relating to eye'*. It may be obscure to the ordinary audience.

> **Opthalmic diseases** is a *professional* or *technical* term, the plain English of which is *"eye diseases"*.

Answer (score 2):

**[Formal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/formal)** is the term you are looking for.

> "Ophthalmic" is too formal, what about "eye diseases"? –